# Finiteness of certain expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

While working on a model of the activity in a slot machines lounge, I encountered that the following formula should be finite:

$$
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{i}{c}\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}
^{c-1}\binom{i-1}{c-j-1}q^{i+j-c}p^{c-j},
$$

but I've not been able to prove it. I would thank very much any suggestion.

Comment: I forgot to say that $p$ and $q=1-p$ are fixed probabilities (i.e., $0<p<1$), while $c$ is a positive integer value.

Comment: I am not experienced in these kinds of problems. But have you tried writing $q=\alpha p$, for finite $\alpha$? This way the expression becomes $\frac{1}{c} \sum_{i} iq^i \sum_j {i-1 \choose c-j-1} \alpha^{c-j} $. Also know [this identity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bj%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D+%7Bn+choose+j%7D+a%5Ej)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ denote the sum. Substituting $k = c - 1 - j$ and interchanging the order of summation,

\begin{align*}
S
&= \frac{1}{c} \sum_{k=0}^{c-1} \frac{p^{k+1}}{k!} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{i!}{(i-1-k)!} q^{i-1-k} \\
&= \frac{1}{c} \sum_{k=0}^{c-1} \frac{p^{k+1}}{k!} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial q}\right)^{k+1} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} q^{i} \\
&= \frac{1}{c} \sum_{k=0}^{c-1} \frac{p^{k+1}}{k!} \frac{(k+1)!}{(1-q)^{k+2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{c} \sum_{k=0}^{c-1} \frac{k+1}{p} \\
&= \frac{c+1}{2p}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice calculation! Thank you very much!